# Add User To Skype Conference Call

Tags: vb.net, skype, skype4com

I'm simply trying to add a user to a Skype group call, not making a new call with them. Is there some command that makes this possible?

I've tried using this:

```
Skype.ActiveCalls(1).Participants.Add(...)
```

But it requires a Skype4COMLib.Participant variable, and I'm lost on how to interact with that.